# Generate URL Without Index Using Tag Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an action link that looks like this

```
<a asp-controller="Complaint" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@complaint.Id">
```

This will then generate the link /Complaints/Index/be8cd27e-937f-4b7d-9004-e6894d1eebea

I'd like the link to not have Index. I've tried to add a new route to Startup but with no success.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "defaultNoAction",
    "{controller=Complaint}/{action=Index}/{id}");
```

I can't find any documentation to see if it's possible to generate the URL with tag helpers without Index. Perhaps someone here knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate your controller's action with a route attribute that would have the route you need.

```
[Route("Complaints/{id}")]
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

This way your controller's action becomes the default one. Please make sure other methods have different signature.

**UPDATE**

To set up routing in `Startup` class it's important to define the order of routing rules correctly. Per [ASP.NET Routing Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html#routing-basics):

> The route collection is processed in order. Requests look for a match in the
>   route collection by URL matching. Responses use routing to generate
>   URLs.

This means your specific rules should go first, and the default route template should go afterwards like a catch-all rule. In your case the following should do the trick.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "complaints",
        template: "complaints/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Complaints", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, why then did the MapRoute not work, and attribute routing did?

Comment: I would guess the order of routes collection was wrong. I've just updated my answer to include this routing approach as well.

Comment: Using the routing based approach works, but has an unintended side affect. If I add a new action, lets call it 'Add', and I navigate to /Complaints/Add/ it will navigate to /Complaints/

Comment: That's why I prefer using routing attributes in controller, and would recommend that approach.