# Core 3.1 to Net 5.0 problem with route. The view show QBarcore

Tags: asp.net-core

I click on the link to open the view Index and show me Qbarcode.
I check  what is path show me http://localhost:56999/LIMS_LineSamples it missed the Index.
I write http://localhost:56999/LIMS_LineSamples/Index work correct.

In my _layout have the following  code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle  text-dark" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Incoming Orders </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="LABApp_InboxSamples" asp-action="Index">Incoming Order from SAP</a>
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="LIMS_LineSamples" asp-action="Index">Incoming Line Samples </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

On my Startup.cs have the following code for map:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

if add controller:

```
[Route("LABApp_InboxSamples")]
[Route("LABApp_InboxSamples/Index")]
[Route("LABApp_InboxSamples/Index/{id?}")]
public ActionResult Index()
    {
```

It works fine. It is another way to get back the app work like Core 3.1.

Comment: I believe that this will resolve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175589/generate-url-without-index-using-tag-helpers

Comment: Edrian, thank you very much for the link. It helps me to clarify.